Output shape when subtracting multi dimensional array using broadcasting?
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
p = data - a[:, np.newaxis]
print(p)

I am getting output as:
[[[1 2],
  [3 4]],
 [[0 1],
  [2 3]]]

What I was expecting is:
[[[1,2]],
 [[2,3]]]

NumPy should just broadcast data to the shape of a and perform element wise subtraction. Can anyone tell me why I am getting that output?

You are using a (2,2) with a (2,1,2).  Producing a (2,2,2).  You want a (1,2,2)

@hpaulj why broadcasting (2,2) and (2,1,2) produces an array of(2,2,2)?

As explained in your previous question, dimensions are paired starting from the end. (2,2) becomes (1,2,2).  And the 1's expand to 2.

I was wrong, you want (2,1,2), so you need both arguments to start with (2,1,2).  A (2,2) paired sith (2,1,2) becomes a (1,2,2).  The rules for automatically adding a dimension have to be narrowly defined to avoid ambiguities.

@hpaulj like you said a (2,2) paired with (2,1,2) becomes (1,2,2), does 1 always added in beginning of the array with smaller dimension  and if no why just we haven't added 1 in middle of (2,2)

To avoid ambiguity, new dimrnsions are only added at the start.  Anything else you have to add yourself.  Adding dimensions and adjusting size 1 dimensions are two separate steps.

You should create the new axis after subtraction:
p = (data - a)[:, np.newaxis]

Or add a new axis to both operands:
p = data[:, np.newaxis] - a[:, np.newaxis]

Output:
array([[[1, 2]],

       [[2, 3]]])

